# Why does V8 give this confusing error message?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, v8

On chrome/node (v8 in general i suppose), the following gives an error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: f is not iterable

```js
function f(){}
f(...undefined);
```

Why does it generate such an ambiguous error message? Imho, this has nothing to do with `f`?

E.g. on firefox (spidermonkey), i get an understandable "undefined has no properties". If i use an object (`let o = {}; f(...o.p);`), i get an even more accurate "o.p is undefined".

This has probably been asked before, but i have no clue what to search for - "function not iterable" gives a ton unrelated results.

PS: just as a fun fact, obviously, the error will not go away, if `f` is made iterable: `f[Symbol.iterator] = function*() {};`. The error message seems to be plain wrong.

Comment: It's just a wrong error message.  It's trying to call `f()` and ran into an error when collecting the arguments and wrongly attributed the error to `f`.

Comment: I guess it is just wrong. It occurred in a rather complex, higher order function call. The issue took me 5-10 minutes, before i noticed, that one of the spread parameters was `undefined`, because of a very simple mistake. In that case, it wasn't immediately clear, that the error message was just completely off. Had it not been that obvious, that one argument was `undefined`, i'd probably still be trying to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

V8 developer here. This looks like a bug. Please file a bug at [crbug.com/v8/new](https://crbug.com/v8/new).

Comment: Thanks! On the linked site, i found there is an [open issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=10038) for this bug already.

Comment: Good news: the bug has been fixed! The fix will be in V8 8.2 / Chrome 82.